# Nuclear fusion ignited by neutron capture

Tags: nuclear-physics, fusion

Does anybody know if there was some attempt to make a hydrogen (fusion) bomb using neutrons released from the fission primary?

e.g. using [$^{10}\text{B}$ hydrate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boranes) as a fuel? Assuming reaction

$$^{10}\text{B} + \text{n} \rightarrow  ^7\text{Li} + ^4\text{He} + 2.4 \text{ MeV}$$

$$\text{p} + ^7\text{Li} \rightarrow 2^4\text{He} + 17.2 \text{ MeV}$$

I know that by itself it is not worth it to use a neutron for fusion to release just ~20 MeV while fission of U235 or Pu239 caused by the same neutron  can release ~200 MeV.
But if this 20 MeV can heat the fusion fuel from inside to ignite self-sustained burn it could be worth it. At least it could be used as kind of spark (like in [fast ignition](https://lasers.llnl.gov/science/ignition/fast-ignition) in laser driven inertial fusion ) for pre-compressed fuel (maybe?)

Is this idea completely stupid? Or [ignition by adiabatic compression of fuel by X-ray radiation pressure](http://nuclearweaponarchive.org/Nwfaq/Nfaq4-4.html#Nfaq4.4) (which is how current H-bombs work) is just much more efficient?

And possibly is there any possibility to use such approach for more controlled fusion reaction (like for fusion power plant, or fusion propelled spacecraft)?